# Why Font becoming blur while exporting as .png? How to export correctly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

While exporting image from Photoshop, The text is slightly loosing its sharpness.

But When I take the same as screenshot (or by using the snipping tool)the sharpness remains.

The following image is showed for comparing both **exported from Photoshop** and **using snipping tool**
[image: compare]

Please help to solve the exporting issue to export exact font.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the exported image shown at 100% size and is the screenshot made when viewing the image at 100%?

Comment: exported in 100% and in the same view i took snip shot @Wolff

Comment: How do you export?

Comment: file-> export -> quick export as png

Comment: I can't replicate the issue - maybe you have some effects applied. Have you checked the *Export > Export Preferences*? Have you tried to use *Export > Save for Web (Legacy)* to see if the result is the same? Have you tried to just *Layer > Flatten Image* for comparison?

Comment: yes i tried all options and finally posted. thanks.

Comment: Then please add your findings to the question so we can narrow down what's going on. What happened when you tried all those things? Does this problem also occur if you make a new file? If not, what could be the difference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101236/discussion-between-ramlal-s-and-wolff).